# Is there an efficient way to get a full count and results (with LIMIT) in one SQL call?

Tags: sql, sqlite, pdo

I'm using PHP PDO with SQLite to select some rows with a limit but want to also get the total number of possible results.

Right now I can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE XXX
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE XXX LIMIT 30
```

But that's two database calls that feel like they may somehow be able to be merged into one.  I could also do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE XXX
```

And do the `COUNT` and `LIMIT` via PHP.  Though that database call will return hundreds maybe thousands of rows and columns of data that will just be ignored outside of counting.

Might there be some cool SQL or PDO way of doing what I want in one database call without return excess data?  If not... is there a recommended method between the two options I presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just include a non correlated count subquery in the outer select:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE xxx) AS cnt,
    t.*
FROM yourTable t
WHERE XXX
ORDER BY t.some_col
LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: Ok, so that would just add a cnt column to every row?  Still not ideal, but better than anything I've come up with so far. Thanks.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed In fact SQLite should only need to evaluate that count query once, cache it, and then reuse the value for every row.  So, it is not as inefficient as it might look to the naked eye.

Answer (score 0):

The more recent versions of SQLite support window functions, so you can do:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER () as num_rows
FROM table t
WHERE XXX
LIMIT 30;
```

In earlier versions, I would recommend a CTE:

```
with t as (
      SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE XXX
     )
select t.*, (select count(*) from t)
from t
limit 30;
```

This way, you don't have to repeat the conditions -- something that might be prone to error.